# How to Track Google Analytics on a Redirection Page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, google-analytics

I have a website that is driving traffic to over 600 other websites. In order to track the traffic that we provide to our partners, we've created a redirection page in between our website and the website we're driving traffic to.

We want to use this redirection website to track information overall, like how much traffic did we refer per day/week/month etc. But also to find out information per partner, since they all sell something different, so we run different marketing campaigns for them. So we want to know the demographics for each of our partners.

I was thinking of setting up a general goal in analytics on the redirect page in order to track the overall information, is that the best way? And what would you suggest for individual partners?

Thank you so much in advance!

Regards,
Molle

Comment: How is the redirection done? I wouldn't think the analytics JS would fire with a redirection.

Comment: UTM parameters will help you... set the source and medium for each :)